# Is it possible to use the Mocha Framework against a model in Sails.js?

Tags: mocha.js, sails.js

Sails.js uses the MVC pattern for Node.js and I was wondering if Mocha could be hooked up for testing Models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you asked this awhile ago, but I was searching around myself and there's not much out there at the moment. I figured I'd drop what I found into this answer...

I found some discussion on the [sails github](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/529) and [a gist](https://gist.github.com/joukokar/57b14e034e41893407f0) with some example code.

There is also a [second discussion](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/797) with more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the links Matt. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [wolfpack](https://github.com/fdvj/wolfpack). It's a SailsJS model-testing library that allows you to test Sails models without the need for a db or lifting your sails app.