# Sails.js and Mocha: Using supertest to create a new model

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, sails.js, supertest

I'm currently setting up testing infrastructure for my Sails app, and it was going smoothly until I tried testing API requests with `supertest`.

I'm trying to test some of my controller methods (that I implemented instead of using the default blueprint routes), but it seems like the API request isn't even going through. The reason I think this is because I can run `npm test` and this code will run fine, but if I change the POST path to `/datamodel/create5`, where `create5()` does NOT exist as a controller method, it still runs fine... In both cases, a DataModel model is NOT created. I've included some code below.

This is what my code looks like:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var assert = require('assert');
var async = require('async');
var stubs = require('../stubs.js');

describe('DataModel', function() {
  var testDataModel;
  var dataModelParams = stubs.dataModelStub(); // simply returns a JSON dictionary

  describe('#create()', function() {
    describe('data model import', function() {
      it('should import a new data model.', function (done) {
        var agent = request.agent(sails.hooks.http.app);

        agent
          .post('/datamodel/create')
          .send(dataModelParams)
          .expect(302)
          .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
              throw new Error(err);
            }
            console.log(res.dataModel);

            DataModel.find().exec(function (err, dataModels) {
              console.log(dataModels); // should return an array of 1 model but returns empty array instead
              done();
            });
          });
      });
  });
});
```

Snippet of my controller code:

```
  create: function(req, res) {
    DataModel.create(req.params.all(), function dataModelCreated(err, dataModel) {
      if (err) {
        sails.log.debug(err);
      }

      FlashService.success(req, 'Successfully imported a new data model.');
      fs.ensureDirSync(path.join(sails.config.paths.DATASET_EXTRACT_PATH, dataModel.fileSafeName));
      fs.ensureDirSync(path.join(sails.config.paths.DATASET_DOWNLOAD_ROOT, 'non_pii', dataModel.fileSafeName));
      fs.ensureDirSync(path.join(sails.config.paths.DATASET_DOWNLOAD_ROOT, 'pii', dataModel.fileSafeName));
      fs.ensureDirSync(path.join(sails.config.paths.DATASET_ENCRYPT_PATH, dataModel.fileSafeName));
      return res.redirect('/admin/manage_data_models');
    });
  }
```

Note that the `create` function runs correctly in practice when my app is launched. Any suggestions as to why my test isn't working properly? I'm using `sails-memory` for the tests if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to authenticate my agent first (by making a call to the login route) before any of these calls would make it through.

Essentially:

```
var agent = request.agent(sails.hooks.http.app);
agent.post('YOUR_LOGIN_ROUTE').end(done);

// do your tests
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, don't you need to pass something that looks like the sails app to supertest? There's an example here that shows what you need to do. Look at the before function in the second answer:

[How to test controller using mocha in Sails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689201/how-to-test-controller-using-mocha-in-sails)

Comment: Yup, I tried ```http://localhost:1337``` as well as ```sails.hooks.http.app```, but both resulted in the same problem. It's in the 13th line of the test snippet.